# A problem about convergence of sequences

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis

Suppose $(a_n) $ is a bounded divergent sequence. I want to know if it is true that there is a point in the real line, and of course between the upper bound and the lower bound of the sequence such that an infinite number of points are in one side of that point and another infinitely many of points are on the other side of that?
If it was true I tried to approach by way of contradiction and said suppose there is not such a point so if we consider any point in the real line there are infinitely many points of the sequence just in one side of that point and finite number of points on the other side. So won't it lead to the contradiction that $(a_n) $ is convergent?

Please help with your advices.
Would be gratful

Answer (score 2):

If $(a_n)$ is bounded and divergent, then $L=\liminf_na_n<M=\limsup_na_n$. You can find subsequences $(a_{n_k})$ and $(a_{n_j})$ such that $a_{n_k}\to M$, $a_{n_j}\to L$. Now show that for $k,j$ big enough, $a_{n_k}<(L+M)/2<a_{n_j}$.

Comment: I was going to say that a bounded real sequence is divergent if and only if it has at least two distinct limit points, so the midpoint of any two such limit points would do the trick. But I think your statement is better because it produces two such limit points explicitly. +1 for you.